# django-csp -- Why I am getting CSP violation error even if nonce is set up?

Tags: python, django, django-csp

I am getting error in my browser as

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src-elem 'self' 'self' [https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/"](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/%22). Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-lcRjLlr3aCdbAn5uZatA01Jri58xjpKG86fd61W4h9Y='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

I am using [django-csp](https://django-csp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) to set up Content Security Policy. In my `settings.py`, I have included the following.

```py
MIDDLEWARE = [
    # added middleware
    'csp.middleware.CSPMiddleware',
    ...
]

CSP_DEFAULT_SRC = ["'self'", ]
CSP_INCLUDE_NONCE_IN = ['script-src']
```

I have written the JavaScript as -

```js
<script nonce="{{ request.csp_nonce }}">
    do_something()
</script>
```

Please help me to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have only included `script-src` and not `script-src-elem`

`settings.py` will be:

```
CSP_INCLUDE_NONCE_IN = [
    'script-src',
    'script-src-elem'
]
```